# Android - bindService at fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity Class and at it's `onResume` part I've used the next code -

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, IMService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

At the `onPause` I've used the next code -

```
@Override
protected void onPause() 
{       
    unbindService(mConnection);
    super.onPause();
}
```

As you can understand I'm binding and unbinding to a Service.

Now the thing is that I want to use fragment instead of Activity.

In order to do that I've changed the onPuse code into this -

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() 
{       
    getActivity().unbindService(mConnection);
    super.onPause();
}
```

And it seems fine.

But the thing I have problem with is the bind part at the `onResume`, I've tried the next code -

```
            @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
 bindService(new Intent(getActivity(), IMService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

But Eclipse gives me an error saying -

```
The method bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) is undefined for the type MainFragment
```

the service is showing like this at the manifest -

```
    <service android:name="com.example.test.services.IMService" >
    </service>
```

So why I can't bind the Service into the fragment? Maybe I need to add something to the getActivity code?

Thnks for any kind of help

Thanks for @Raghunandan help - this is the solution-

```
getActivity().bindService(new Intent(getActivity(), IMService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int). bindService Requires a context

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use

```
getActivity().bindService(params)
```

It requires a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29)

Comment: Thanks man - that's the solution. So simple but yet so frustrating

Comment: i think it should be getActivity() instead of getActivity

Answer (score 4):

start:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OdometrService.class);
   getActivity().bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

stop:

```
getActivity().unbindService(connection);
```